# How does this site not load as it goes to another page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

If you go to [this site](http://www.hugoandmarie.com/#/news) and navigate, you'll notice there is no load between pages. Everything is smooth. I am not sure how this is done. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Looks like you answered your own question with your tags, it is using some form of ajax. As you might notice, it doesn't really change urls, it just changes the hash part of the url (`#/creative`).

Comment: its similar to alot of links found in facebook and twitter, its search engine friendly apparently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its crawlable ajax, this may provide some insight into it.

http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

Since the site doesn't even load with NoScript on, my first guess it heavy JavaScript use. However, browsing the page, no actual http requests are made for it to qualify as AJAX. Profiling the JS actions when switching pages, you can quickly find links to their core JS files

```
http://www.hugoandmarie.com/includes/backbone/controllers.js
http://www.hugoandmarie.com/includes/backbone/views.js
```

It would appear they're using a JavaScript-recreating-DOM MVC architecture.

You do that by loading your content into JavaScript and then using the [DOM functions](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html) to write the content into the page.

Answer (score 0):

i disagree with jeremy.  Zend's files may load quickly, but it doesn't mean they don't have to be loaded or that there is no load time.  like gnur said, it's done with ajax or javascript DOM.  Ajax can use javascript to add dynamic content to the page by accessing server files and loading new information into the html without having to load a whole new page.